# why my domain of x-axis not be plotted all?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

May anyone help me about the plot of graph.

My coding of python given as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np

x=[-0.006,-0.005,-0.004,-0.003,-0.002,-0.001,0,0.001,0.002,0.003,0.004,0.005,0.006]
x = np.array(x)
y = 220*(1 -(0.85*np.exp(-np.pi**2/np.log(2)*(x*0.53e-9/((759.5e-9)**2)**2))))

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('optical path difference')
plt.ylabel('coincidence counts in 3 min')
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph]

why the graph not start from x=0.006?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because for negative values of x and takes -inf:

x:

```
[-0.006 -0.005 -0.004 -0.003 -0.002 -0.001  0.     0.001  0.002  0.003
  0.004  0.005  0.006]
```

y:

```
[ -inf  -inf  -inf  -inf  -inf  -inf   33.  220.  220.  220.  220.  220.
  220.]
```

And these can not be plotted, so matplotlib eliminates them. If we force it to show the side that is -0.006 to 0 we will observe the following (`plt.xlim([-0.006, 0.006])`):

[image]

Comment: thank you for your comment. suppose I get the reflection of the right graph. It must look like as V curve with the value of y for x=-0.006 till 0.001 same as the value of y for x=0.001 till 0.006. How can I make it?

Comment: change to: `y = 220*(1 -(0.85*np.exp(-np.pi**2/np.log(2)*(np.abs(x)*0.53e-9/((759.5e-9)**2)**2))))` and you get the following: http://imgur.com/a/lx0NO

Comment: thankyou very much . Yes, I want the graph to be like that. I try it.